# Cloud functions: call a second function when the first has finished

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I execute a second cloud function when the first has finished?

I'd like to call a new cloud function, not a normal js function, in order to reduce each function execution time. Also I need a serial execution, not parallell (the second function queries data updated by the first)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you need an orchestrator. Run a pipeline, call your first functions, then call the second functions (then whatever!!)

My preferred is https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/overview: serverless, cheap, perfect for working with Cloud Functions

Or you can use the heavy and expensive [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer)